# Used a “slim” version of XP on an acquaintance’s computer… now I discover he needs features I cut out

Tags: windows-xp, internet-explorer, system-restore, outlook-express

I “gave away” my copy of XP because I didn’t need it anymore. An acquaintance of mine had his system crash, and I put that copy of XP onto a spare computer (that couldn’t handle anything more than XP anyhow). Problem is, I used a “slim” copy of XP that I had customized for myself, to remove everything that I did not personally need (I couldn’t find the original disk at the time).

Among the things removed, he needs two features re-enabled.

One is Outlook Express. He has OE files that he still accesses on a regular basis, and he prefers OE to all other email clients. I had removed Internet Explorer completely from the original slim, but installed (and hid) IE8 so that he could manually do Windows Updates whenever he wanted. How do I get OE back onto the system? The IE6 installer (which piggybacks OE6) quits when it finds IE8.

The second is System Restore. I never understood the need for system restore, as it often caused far more problems for me than it solved. Plus, until recently what I had available for boot drives was very constrained -- I didn’t want to waste the space. Unfortunately, he really, really wants System Restore back. I know it is fully excised from the system because it doesn’t even show up as a tab in System Properties… there are only six tabs, not seven available.

I am hoping to re-enable these two features without having to re-install XP.

Comment: Did you find the original disk?

Comment: I have found it again. Why?

Comment: Because, the answer maxwellb was what I was going to post, but it would require the original disk if you stripped the libraries from the install disk you originally used.

Comment: @AthomSfere: Can an nLited copy of XP can have its missing components restored if you simply pop in the CD and use Add/Remove Windows Components? No harm in trying of course, but are you sure it'll work?

Comment: @Karan I was saying if he found the original (retail or oem) disk, not the nLite or whatever slipstream disk he used.

Comment: @AthomSfere: Of course, that goes without saying. What would be the point of using the nLited disc again, right? I'm not sure even the original disc will work, but the OP should definitely give it a go and report back.

Answer (score 1):

1. Control Panel
2. Add or Remove Programs
3. Add/Remove Windows Components
4. Outlook Express

For your IE8 woes, unhide the IE8 install (Restore hidden updates), and then uninstall it.

Comment: Are you sure this will work with an nLited copy of XP that has had components stripped out completely from the installation image itself?

Comment: Give it a go. What have you got to lose?

Comment: Unfortunately, using the Add/Remove Windows Components rarely affects files on the drive itself, it just modifies their ability to function. For example, if you use that utility to “remove” Internet Explorer, you don’t actually remove it -- you just remove all the shortcuts to it.

In my case, the problem I have is that there is no sr.ini file (nor associated files) for System Restore, nor a service available for it. Same goes for Outlook Express - the c:/Program Files/Outlook Express/ directory is completely empty.